# Retrieve data from database and return into text box using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, uwp

```
using (var db = new CrabContext())
{
    var query = db.Reading.Select(s => new
                                       { s.Left1 })
                          .Select(x => x.ToString());
    t1.Text = query;
    //t1.Text == db.Reading.Select(s => new { s.Left1 });
}
```

I am here trying to retrieve data from database as per mentioned above but my t1.Text is not able to retrieve the data yet I get an error like

> Can't implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable ' to 'String'

Answer (score 3):

It's because the `.Select()` returns an `IQueryable`, an `IQueryable` is not accessible because the type of the data is not specified so it's only accessible when compiling, if you want to have the value directly prefer to use `FirstOrDefault` you can pass a lambda expression inside to retrieve a specific object.

```
using (var db = new CrabContext())
{
    var query = db.Reading.FirstOrDefault();
    t1.Text = query.Left1;
}
```

But with the solution I provide the call make to the Db is `SELECT * FROM Reading` and then you access the property Left1
With `IQueryable` the query is `SELECT Left1 FROM Reading` but you can't access the property... 
Another solution will be to call `.toList()` at the end of your query...

Comment: If you're using `FirstOrDefault`, then it's better to include `null` checking so that OP would understand that.